# Best practice for X11 application - one XOpenDisplay per application, or per window?

Tags: c++, x11

So I'm working on developing some code that uses the X11 library to work with X-Windows on Linux. I've found some simple tutorials, but they don't go into many details about best practices for more practical use-cases.

One thing I'm wondering is, should I be making one call to XOpenDisplay per application and passing around the pointer to the Display, or is it okay to call this function for each top-level window?

Comment: There's two reasons for what you're doing: You need a GUI for something or you want to learn. For the former, using a widget set on top of X11 is probably more productive. For the latter, consider using XCB instead of Xlib, since it is closer to the actual protocol. Good luck!

Comment: It's for a high performance 3D application (similar to a game engine) for which little in the way of native GUI features are needed, and for which I would like to limit dependencies and maximize range. I think using something like Qt would be a bit heavy for what I need, which is mainly just the creation and management of up to a small handful of simple top level windows, with the rest being done through OpenGL. (There are reasons that I prefer to avoid GLUT and SDL as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use more than one connection to X server in your appilcation, there is a good reason not to do this: every connection is assigned range of resource IDs (even if your client does not create its own resources), and resource id is 32bit number, thus total number of connection is limited in X11 ([and is usually as low as 256 to 512 on most systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25273/what-is-the-max-number-of-x-clients))

Answer (score 2):

You should only need `XOpenDisplay` once. One Display can have many windows.

Comment: Is this true? I've found that it seems to need to be called once per thread, unless I want the application freezing, needing a second `XOpenDisplay` for the seemingly mundane task of having a secondary thread send messages to a window.